# What is more important, energy or entropy?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, entropy

What decides if something will change or remain the same? Energy or entropy considerations?

Comment: Depends on the system. In some systems entropy plays no role whatsoever (because we are looking at only one or a few mechanical degrees of freedom and there are no internal degrees of freedom that we need to take into account) and in others (like in chemistry) both play a role. Finally there are plenty of inhomogeneous non-equilibrium systems in which entropy can't tell us anything about the evolution and other methods are needed to understand the dynamics. I would count self-organizing "synergistic" systems among these and entropy is not very useful near certain phase transitions, either.

Comment: @CuriousOne. Could you please name a system with " one or a few mechanical degrees of freedom where there are no internal degrees of freedom to take into account"? ( thank you for your remark )

Comment: The Kepler problem. No entropy involved. Temperature irrelevant and undefined. Coupled harmonic oscillators. You don't need thermodynamics for those and strictly speaking statistical mechanics won't work because the ergodic hypothesis is not valid.

Comment: What is the "something" that "will change?" And what kind of change are you talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about the spontaneity of a process, then the enthalpy(not energy!) and entropy both are equally important. Actually, it is determined by the Gibbs free  energy which is a function of both, given by $\Delta G=\Delta H-T\Delta S$. The condition for spontaneity is that the Gibbs Free energy be negative. This can be shown as follows-

$\Delta S_{total}=\Delta S_{surr}+\Delta S_{sys}$

Also, $\Delta S_{surr}=\frac{q_{rev}}{T}=\frac{\Delta H_{surr}}{T}=\frac{-\Delta H_{sys}}{T}$ (By definition).

So $\Delta S_{total}=\Delta S_{sys} + (\frac{-\Delta H_{sys}}{T})$. rearranging,

$T\Delta S_{total}=T\Delta S_{sys}-\Delta H_{sys}$. For Spontaneity, $\Delta S_{total}>0$, hence

$T\Delta S-\Delta H>0$ or $-\Delta G>0$; giving

$\Delta G<0$ for a spontaneous process.

So, it actually depends on which OUTWEIGHS the other-energy or entropy-which decides the direction of the process.( Because maybe entropy has DECREASED, but if $\Delta H$ is negative enough to outweigh it and keep the Gibbs energy negative, the process is still spontaneous forward).

NOTE- My convention for the above calculation is- Heat absorbed by the system is +ve and released is -ve. Work done ON the system is positive and done BY the system is negative. You can choose your own convention and change the signs accordingly.